how to force <link> in NextJs to use single click only
I'm using Flickity-React-Component for a swappable Carousel and passed NextJs <Link> to its children.
The problem is when click and swap the carousel, after releasing mouse click it opens that link
is there a way to force it to use single click?
Here's my code :
 <Flickity
                options={{
                    freeScroll: true,
                    contain: true,
                    wrapAround : true,
                    prevNextButtons: false,
                    pageDots: false,
                    initialIndex: 2,
                }}>

                {slides?.length && slides.map((item, idx) => {
                    return (
                        // <Link key={`banner_${item.id}`} href={`/${item.shop_link}`}>
                        <div>
                            <Image src={item.src} />
                        </div>
                        // </Link>
                    )
                })}
            </Flickity>

sorry for my bad English
I've changed <Link> with onCLick event and it doesn't work

Did you used ? next/router

Have you tried using  only?

I used next/navigation because i'm using nextJs app Router
And  tag will result the same

I think single click behavior while using Next.js  component within the Flickity carousel, you can use the preventDefault method to stop the default link behavior and handle the navigation programmatically
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Carousel = ({ slides }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    router.push(`/${item.shop_link}`);
  };

  return (
    <Flickity
      options={{
        freeScroll: true,
        contain: true,
        wrapAround: true,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        initialIndex: 2,
      }}
    >
      {slides?.length && slides.map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={`banner_${item.id}`} onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>
          <Image src={item.src} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </Flickity>
  );
};

export default Carousel;

useRouter from next/router is used to trigger navigation with router.push

It didn't work.
